# Typescript cannot add Object to Map

Tags: typescript

I try to add to a <number, Entity> map and then get the Entity by the number assigned, but it is not working properly.
After adding an Entity to the map console.log(this.entities.keys()) prints [Map Iterator] {1}, which seems to be correct. But a console.log(JSON.stringify(this.entities)); just prints {}

```
private entities: Map<number, Entity>;
private lastId = 0;

constructor(entities?: Map<number, Entity>, lastId?: number) {
    this.entities = entities || new Map<number, Entity>();
    this.lastId = lastId || 0;
}

public addEntity(entity: Entity): number {
    this.entities.set(++this.lastId, entity);
    console.log(this.entities.keys()); //Logs: [Map Iterator] {1}
    return this.lastId;
}

public getEntity(entityId: number): Entity | undefined {
    let temp = this.entities.get(entityId);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.entities)); //Logs: {}
    return temp;
}
```

My Entity Class looks like this:

```
export class Entity {
private position = new Array<number>(3);
private orientation = new Array<number>(4);
private scale = new Array<number>(3);
private model: string;
private texture: string;

constructor(position: number[], orientation: number[], scale: number[], model: string, texture: string) {
    this.position = position;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.model = model;
    this.texture = texture;
}
}
```

Comment: *"But a console.log(JSON.stringify(this.entities)); just prints {}"* That's correct. `Map` instances have no enumerable properties, so you get `{}` for them when you convert them to JSON. If you want your JSON to contain the `Map` entries, you have to convert the map to something JSON-compatible first (perhaps via `[...theMap.entries()]`. Seeing `{}` doesn't mean the `Map` is empty.

Comment: The rather more direct way to see if you stored the entry would be to use `this.entries.get(this.lastId)` and look at the result.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to debug it. The problem was that, even though getEntitiy() wants a number, entityId was a string. Thanks for that Typescript!